# iCloud (re)uploading all my documents again

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, backup, time-machine, temperature

I have recently bought a new Macbook Pro 13" (i7, 16GB) and to do the switch from the old one to this one, I have installed Mojave and restored it from my other Macbook Pro's Time Machine backup. This have been done without any problem.

The problem comes with the iCloud sync. With the old Macbook Pro I was using iCloud to backup all my Documents and Desktop folder on the cloud (not using it for the Photos). Now I have all these files in my new computer (because of the Time Machine restoring), and it seems to be reuploading to the iCloud drive. I suspect that, as these files were transferred from a physical drive where I store the Time Machine backups, the system does not recognise them as if it came from the iCloud drive, and is "reuploading" them in order to compare from the ones in the cloud to check if they are the same, but it is only my intuition.

The annoying part is that there is a process called bird (I have researched a little bit and it is in charge of the iCloud file syncing) is using nearly 100% of the CPU, which is all the time at 90ºC-95ºC (as reported by iStats), and due to that, my fans are running at full speed all the time.

I realized also that in the finder window, next to the iCloud shortcut, there is a circle representing the iCloud progress syncing, and if I click it, it shows me that iCloud is uploading and downloading a large amount of files.

My question is if this is this iCloud behaviour is expected and if it is normal that the bird process uses such amount of CPU, causing all this heating.

I attach a screenshot showing the iStats status right now in order to illustrate the problem.

[image: iStats screenshot]

If any additional information is required, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same behaviour on my new machine...

Comment: @animaldesequia did you find a solution for this?